# Cross-NFS file move adds ACL

Tags: linux, nfs, acl

Moving a file from one NFS4 mount to another adds an ACL. The reason, if I understand the process correctly, is that `mv` queries the `system.nfs4_acl` extended attribute of the source file, and uses the response to set the same attribute on the destination file. The problem is, if the source file has no ACL at all, the server makes up this attribute based on the file mode. But, such a made-up ACL is not removed when setting it (that would be weird, of course, if some ACLs would be silently dropped when setting them).

I have discovered one fix, so far, which is to add `system.nfs4_acl skip` to `/etc/xattr.conf`. This makes `mv` ignore the fake ACL, and makes the problem go away. It feels slightly wrong though. Does anyone know of a way to stop the server from making up this fake ACL in the first place?